# How do you select different locations across multiple lines in vim?

Tags: vim

How would I select the **space** before the `~` on each line so that I can run the same command on each line or edit text on that line?

Example:

```
ln -sF $DOTFILES/.vim ~/
ln -sF $DOTFILES/hyper.js ~/.hyper.js
ln -sF $DOTFILES/vimrc ~/.vimrc
```

**Note** that the character positions are different so `ctrl-v`would not properly work here as your second line would have me inserting in-between the `r` and `.` which is **not** what I want.

I want to be inserting text between the **space** and `~` on each line?

Answer (score 2):

### With a substitution

1. Visually select the whole block:

   ```
   vip
   ```
2. Perform a substitution:

   ```
   :'<,'>s/\ze\~/yourtexthere
   ```

### With a macro

1. Visually select the whole block:

   ```
   vip
   ```
2. Run a simple macro:

   ```
   :'<,'>norm! f~iyourtexthere
   ```

### With a recording:

1. Record your macro:

   ```
   qq
   f~iyourtexthere<Esc>j
   q
   ```
2. Play it again:

   ```
   @q@q
   ```

### With repetition

1. Search for that tilde:

   ```
   / \ze\~
   ```
2. Do your change:

   ```
   ayourtexthere<Esc>
   ```
3. Repeat on next matches:

   ```
   n.n.
   ```

Comment: looks more like simply find / search instead of visually selecting different locations

Comment: Well, "selecting" is generally not needed in Vim so I went with canonical solutions to your problem. But if you absolutely *want* multiple non-contiguous selection you can try one of the handful of "multiple selection" plugins available because Vim doesn't have such a feature built in.